# twitter WebResponse freezing C#

Tags: c#, .net, twitter, httpwebresponse

ok i am facing a really strange problem with the twitter client of mine.

The code i am using for getting twitter timeline is

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
request.Method = "GET";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
string read_string = read.ReadToEnd();
read.Close();
```

The thing is i can call this code any number of times and i get a response. I also use another code to send status messages to twitter. However whenever i send a message for the 2nd time to twitter and then call this code the WebResponse just freezes. No error code it just freezes.

Initially i suspected that i might had something to do with the shared variable with the write code so i seprated them. But still it was to no avail.

Guyz need urgent help on this one, have been trying to solve this for hours but its no use. I can post whole code if required.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you closing your response?

Comment: yes i just added `response.close()` after `read.close()` still freezing....

Comment: Can you add code for sending message?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Ok i just added response.close() to the sender code and now it is working. Thank you very very very very very much, i have been banging my head against the wall on this for quite some time and u solved it in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the Response:

```
response.Close();
```